# Chance that a member in a population is not picked after n repetitions with replacement.

Tags: probability

Lets say I have a population ($\mathbf p$) of 100 people from which I pick the winner of a raffle every day. After $\mathbf n$ days what is the chance that someone has not been picked yet? How would I change my calculation to: after $\mathbf n$ days what is the chance $\mathbf x$ people have not been picked? What about if I picked $\mathbf k$ number of people to win every day?

My initial thought was something like: $\frac{nonpicked - previously picked}{population}$ n times but there are many other conditions that this does not address.

It seems like I need to keep track of the population that has been selected already and I don't understand how to incorporate that into my calculations. The chance should also be **100%** if **(n * k)** < **(p - x)** or if there have not been enough winners picked to even create the chance for the **x** population to be impossible.

I come from a computer science / coding background but I don't know much about probability or how to put these thoughts into a mathematical formula.

Comment: If the picks are independent, the answer to the first question is $(\frac{p-1}{p})^n$ for one person.  Other questions have similar looking answers.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. And yes, the picks are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clarified that the picks are independent,

For the first part, let's say you are the unfortunate individual who is not picked on $n$ successive days,

its $Pr = \left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^n$

Similarly, if the unfortunate people number $x$ including yourself,

$Pr = \left(\dfrac{100-x}{100}\right)^n$